# Wrapping React Native app with Context Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I've been following some [simple tutorial](https://blog.usejournal.com/persisting-user-authentication-in-a-react-native-app-778e028ac816) ([full working source code](https://github.com/linux08/react-native-authentication/tree/master/Context-API-Integration)) to get the idea how to use React's Context together with handling authentication in my React Native app.

This example is using stateful components for views and handling routing the app within component itself, for example, in [`SignInScreen.js`](https://github.com/linux08/react-native-authentication/blob/master/Context-API-Integration/screens/SignInScreen.js):

```
/* SignInScreen.js */

export default class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Please sign in',
    };

    _signInAsync = async (saveToken) => {
        saveToken()
            .then((data) => {
                // ROUTE USER TO "PROTECTED" PART OF THE APP
                this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({ error })
            })

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MyContext.Consumer>
                    {context => ((
                        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={() => this._signInAsync(context.saveToken)} />
                    ))}
                </MyContext.Consumer>
            </View>
        );
    }

};
```

I tried to transform this component into function component and move the signing in logic into my Context Provider like this:

```
/* SignInScreen.js - MODIFIED */

import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

import { MyContext } from '../Provider';

export default const LoginScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <MyContext.Consumer>
        {context => {
          return (
            <Button
              onPress={() => context.signIn()}
              title="Sign In"
            />
          )
        }
      }
      </MyContext.Consumer>
    </View>
  )
};



/* Provider.js */

import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const MyContext = React.createContext();

export default class MyProvider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.getToken = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      this.saveToken = () => AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
      this.removeToken = () => AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');

      this.signIn = () => {
        this.saveToken()
          .then((data) => {
            // this.props.navigation DOES NOT EXIST!!! :(
            this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
          })
          .catch((error) => this.setState({ error }));
      };

      this.state = {
        token: '',
        signIn: this.signIn,
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')
            .then((token) => {
                this.setState({ token })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ error })
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

When I press that "Sign In" button, my provider errors when I try to redirect user (`this.props.navigation.navigate('App');`) because `this.props.navigation` does not exist.

As far as I understood, this is happening because I didn't properly wrap my app with my Context.

This is my main `App.js` file:

```
/* App.js */

import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import MyContext from './Provider';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext>
        <View>
          <AppNavigator />
        </View>
      </MyContext>
    );
  }
}
```

and my `AppNavigator.js`:

```
/* AppNavigator.js */

import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import AuthLoadingScreen from '../screens/AuthLoadingScreen';
import Auth from './AuthNavigator';
import App from './AppTabNavigator';


export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    Auth,
    App,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```

(`AuthNavigator` and `AppTabNavigator` contain only `createStackNavigator()` with my screens defined in it.)

My question is: how can I wrap this app with my Context so that Context Provider is always aware of `navigation` prop and so I could handle logging in and out and routing user from the Context Provider itself?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this by using [`NavigationActions`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html), pretty helpful built-in module designed for this purpose.